# VBA function to print array result in active cell

Tags: vba, function, excel, subroutine

I'd like to write a **function** where the result should print/write an array into a range of cells.

The active cell should be the first element and the next cell below is the second (and so forth). So if, for example, my current active cell is B2 the desired result should be like in the image below.

My code below works only on the Debug.Pring but I just can't figure it out how to actually have it on the excel sheet.

```
Function ShowResult()

Dim strArray() As String
Dim result As String
result = "Maybe I think too much but something's wrong"
strArray = Split(result, " ")

Dim StartRow, i As Integer
StartRow = 1

For i = 0 To UBound(strArray)
    Debug.Print strArray(i)
    'Range("A" & i + StartRow).Value = strArray(i) <--I tried even with this, didn't work!
Next
End Function
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Range("B" & i + StartRow)` what's `startRow`? If 0, you're starting in cell `B0` which is invalid.

Comment: thanks @findwindow I just fixed it in the code. ignore the initial one. Say it's A column. thanks

Comment: Uh cell `A0` is still invalid. It's the row that's the problem XD Edit: just add `StartRow=1` before the loop. But you will miss the first element of the array so instead of `strArray(i)` do `strArray(startrow-1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub ShowResult()

Dim strArray() As String
Dim result As String
result = Application.InputBox("enter string")

strArray = Split(result, " ")

For I = 0 To UBound(strArray)
    Debug.Print strArray(I)
    Cells(I + 1, 1).Value = strArray(I) 'this puts in in column A. change column here or even prompt user for it?
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: how would you call it from a function (can you do it?!)

Comment: @adhg you would need to apply a keyboard shortcut or a button.

Comment: @findwindow,  No need to loop just assign it directly: `Range("A1").Resize(ubound(strArray)+1).Value = Application.Transpose(strArray)`  I doubt it would ever get over 64000 words.

Comment: thank you both!  I add ActiveCell to answer the question in full.

Comment: You stole this from me. I will avenge my hurt feelings. :)

Comment: @adhg lololol don't give me the check mark. I only did this because you asked me. Please give Scott the check mark. Edit: thanks!

Comment: ok, I switched because you asked; however your answer actually solved my problem and his is good with a gotcha (you need to know the size of the array).

Comment: Right. `sub` makes more sense than `function` here. But Scott has been really helpful to me so I want to give him the points ^_^. Thank you.

Comment: @adhg findwindow is being too kind. If this is the answer you used then it should be the one marked as correct. I was joking with him with my last comment.

Comment: @ScottCraner I know you're joking but I really want you to have it ^_^

Comment: Your both AWESOME! thanks for helping. (switched back)

Comment: @adhg UGH LISTEN TO ME NOT SCOTT

Answer (score 7):

Change your Function a little:

```
Function ShowResult() As Variant

Dim strArray() As String
Dim result As String
result = "Maybe I think too much but something's wrong"
strArray = Split(result, " ")

For i = 0 To UBound(strArray)
    Debug.Print strArray(i)
    'Range("A" & i + StartRow).Value = strArray(i) <--I tried even with this, didn't work!
Next

ShowResult = Application.Transpose(strArray)
End Function
```

Then when using you need to select enough cells that it will cover the entire string:

[image]

Then type your formula:

```
=ShowResults()
```

Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter to make it an array formula:

[image]

If done properly excel will put the `{}` around the formula.

Comment: +1 for the result. What if I don't know the range (it can be 1 or 1,000) I just over simplified my question.

Comment: @adhg it's convoluted to use a function for this XD Use a `sub` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also populate the return array in one go and call it using an array formula...maybe..

```
Option Explicit

Function ShowResult() As Variant

Dim strArray() As String
Dim Result As String
Dim i As Integer

Result = "Maybe I think too much something's wrong"
strArray = Split(Result, " ")

ReDim vTemp(LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray), LBound(strArray) To LBound(strArray)) As String
For i = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
    vTemp(i, LBound(strArray)) = strArray(i)
Next
ShowResult = vTemp

End Function
```

Comment: btw, note the second dimension of the array uses lbound twice :)

Comment: ... oh and also, just as an aside, you could also resize the size of the array formula to be the size of the array you are returning. What you have to do there is to resize to 1 cell and then resize the 1st dimension to the size of the data and use the .FormulaArray on the range.